# how do you properly root galaxy s3 i9300 on mac?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I am trying to root my Galaxy S3 i9300 on a Apple Mac.

I followed the instructions [here](http://galaxys3root.com/galaxy-s3-root/how-to-root-galaxy-s3-on-mac-osx/)

But instead of my phone starting up ClockWorkMod recovery, my phone keeps booting up on android recovery.

Any tips on how to go from here?

Answer (score 0):

Try flashing again, while you do tick off the `auto reboot`. Then take the battery out when it’s done flashing.  Then enter ClockworkMod Recovery right away.

PS: Just try if you are ready to experiment. I don't give any guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

I would first of all recommend downloading the newest version of heimdall and using the terminal to do it because the app has problems in my personal experience.

First, boot your device into download mode (vol down, home, power on most devices), then vol up to confirm, then plug your device in. Now from the bin directory of heimdall, write:

```
sudo ./heimdall print-pit
```

To see your partition scheme. If you already know your partition scheme, and don't need to check for the name of your recovery partition, skip this.

```
sudo ./heimdall flash --PARTITION ~/Desktop/recovery.img --no-reboot
```

Replace the path on the end with the path to your recovery image, and the `--PARTITION` the name of your recovery partition. It should be `--RECOVERY` but it is still good to check.

**NOTE**:I always put `--no-reboot` on the end because when I don't, the recovery never seems to flash properly. You can then long press power to turn off, or take your battery out and back in. This could also be the reason that the flash fails for you.